# INGEST_EVAL in splunk field is not showing

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a csv file that is manually uploaded into splunk. I want to perform an INGEST_EVAL on the file however the changes are not propagating after restart. I am not sure why.  Nothing shows. This is the code - what am i doing wrong? do i need to modify any other configuration on the web side of splunk? (the results are not being dispalyed either in the pre-load section that shows the source type).

```
transform.props : 
[myeval]
INGEST_EVAL = eval_user="test"

field.props : 
[myeval]
INDEXED = True

props.config 

[newfieldsourcetest]
TRANSFORMS = myeval
DATETIME_CONFIG = 
INDEXED_EXTRACTIONS = csv
KV_MODE = none
NO_BINARY_CHECK = true
SHOULD_LINEMERGE = false
category = Structured
description = Comma-separated value format. Set header and other settings in "Delimited Settings"
disabled = false
pulldown_type = true
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your file names are incorrect. They should be as described on https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/IngestEval:

- transforms.conf
- fields.conf
- props.conf

You do not provide what version of Splunk Enterprise you are using - 7.2 or above are required.

After making these changes, yours should work.

I'm using the following:

**transforms.conf**

```
INGEST_EVAL = eval_user="test", event_length=length(_raw)
```

**fields.conf**

```
INDEXED = True
```

**props.conf**

```
category = Custom
pulldown_type = 1
SHOULD_LINEMERGE=FALSE
TRANSFORMS=timestampeval
```

Note that for most of these updates, there is no need to restart Splunk - instead you can call http://:8000/en-US/debug/refresh